# filter an array on the basis of some property of the objects of array

Tags: arrays

I have an array with some objects stored in it.
Say I have objects of type application.
Each application object has some information associated with it like applicationType, appId etc.
I need to create seperate arrays for each applicationType.
like everytime I need to fetch out the objects of same applicationType.
i.e at the end i need to have an array that will consist of objects ( that will be arrays of same applicationType)
eg : object at 0th index will be an array of application of applicationType1. 
      object at 1st index will be an array of application  of applicationType 2.
etc....
What is the most efficient way to do this ?

Comment: So you have a simple array of `Application` objects, and need to build an array of arrays, each one being of applications of type == current array position ? In objective C ?

Answer (score 0):

You create the array-of-arrays, then iterate over your original array of objects, find out the type of each & add it to the appropriate array in your array-of-arrays, creating a new one each time you encounter a type for the first time.  You'll need a mapping from types to indices in your array-of-arrays; a map (or dictionary) would be good for that.  In fact, if you have the flexibility, I'd make the array-of-arrays a map/dictionary and cut out the middleman.

Comment: its like if nwe have an array say initialArray consisting of all objects of all types of application.  
we will iterate over initial array, find out the type for each object and for that typem again iterate over that array to find the other objects with that type ?

Comment: @iOSDevD: You could do it in a single pass.  As you check each item's type, if it is one you haven't seen before, add an array to your array-of-arrays, and add an entry for that type to your map/dictionary; either way, add the new item to the array for its type.